# Sum up dictionary elements in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
{'A': ([  0.        ,  1.0 ,  2.0,   3.0,          0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ]),
 'B': ([  0.        ,  4.0,  5.0 ,   6.0,          0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ]),

.
.
.

'Y': ([  0.        ,  7.0,  8.0 ,   9.0,          0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ]),
'Z': ([  0.        ,  10.0,  20.0,   30.0,          0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ])}
```

I want to sum the 2nd, 3rd and 4th elements and make a new dictionary that looks like this:

```
{'A': ([6.0]),
 'B': ([15.0]),

.
.
.

'Y': ([24.0]),
'Z': ([60.0])}
```

What is the pythonic way to do that? I am using Python 2.7. Thanks

Comment: Pythonic way - iterate through the keys of the dictionary and sum the required elements from the values.  `numpy` doesn't know anything about dictionaries.

Answer (score 5):

Use a dictionary comprehension to loop through dict items and sum the values up:

```
{k: v[1:4].sum() for k, v in d.items()}
# {'A': 6.0, 'B': 15.0, 'Y': 24.0, 'Z': 60.0}
```

---

If you want to keep the result as a list:

```
{k: v[1:4].sum(keepdims=True).tolist() for k, v in d.items()}

# {'A': [6.0], 'B': [15.0], 'Y': [24.0], 'Z': [60.0]}
```